# Angular app.run exportar código en un servicio

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo este código para la autenticación de mi aplicación, está trabajando bien pero la implementación de JWT parece estar en el lugar equivocado. Tal vez se pueda delegar algo de esta lógica al servicio `authorizationService`. Antes de todo, es correcto implementar toda esta lógica en el app.run?

```
app.run(runInit);

function runInit($rootScope, $state, $localStorage, authorizationService, SECURE_CONSTANTS, jwtHelper) {

  $rootScope.$state = $state;

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {

    // token doesn't have been setted to localstorage from loggin
    if (!$localStorage.token) {
      if (authorizationService.memorizedState && (!_.has(fromState, 'data.redirectTo') || toState.name !== fromState.data.redirectTo)) {
        authorizationService.clear();
      }
      if (_.has(toState, 'data.authorization') && _.has(toState, 'data.redirectTo')) {
        if (_.has(toState, 'data.memory')) {
          authorizationService.memorizedState = toState.name;
        }
        $state.go(toState.data.redirectTo);
      }
    } else {
      try {

        var token, tokenPayload;

        // sets claims as object
        token = $localStorage.token;
        tokenPayload = jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);

        // token is a good JWT one and have the webUserId claim
        if (tokenPayload && tokenPayload.webUserId) {
          if (toState.name === SECURE_CONSTANTS.MODULES.LOGIN) {
            $state.go(SECURE_CONSTANTS.MODULES.DASHBOARD);
          }
        } 
        // token is a good JWT one but have not the webUserId claim
        else {
          authorizationService.clear();
        }
      } 
      // catch exception if token is corrupted
      catch (exception) {
        authorizationService.clear();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Acá mi servicio `authorizationService`

```
app.factory('authorizationService', authorizationService);

function authorizationService($state, $cookies, $localStorage) {

    this.authorized = false;
    this.memorizedState = null;

    /**
     * Clears authorization data
     */
    var clear = function() {
            this.authorized = false;
            this.memorizedState = null;
            // deletes token to the cookie
            $cookies.remove('token');
            // clears token from local storage
            $localStorage.token = "";
        },
    /**
     * Redirects the user to the page that tries to access before the authorization
     */
        go = function(fallback) {
            this.authorized = true;
            var targetState = this.memorizedState ? this.memorizedState : fallback;
            $state.go(targetState);
        };

    return {
        authorized: this.authorized,
        memorizedState: this.memorizedState,
        clear: clear,
        go: go
    };

}
```

¿Cómo puedo mejorarlo en términos de moludaridad?  Tengo algunas dudas sobre la implementación de `angular.run` en Angularjs.